# curl through the docker container giving error for office365

Tags: docker, unix, airflow, office365

Below is the error when done through a docker container for testing the access to the office365 user. Why it is not getting through? As I want to do this to test the connectivity with office365. Post I can go and implement the notification through Airflow

```
root@ef2ea69fccf8:/opt/airflow# curl -X POST -d '{"Message":{"Subject": "Have you seen this new Mail REST API?", "Importance": "High", "Body": {"ContentType": "HTML", "Content": "It looks awesome!"}, "ToRecipients": [{"EmailAddress": {"Name": "Austin Jackson", "Address": "austin.jackson@XXXX.com"}}]}}' https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/sendmail --header "Content-Type: application/json"  --verbose --user "austin.jackson@XXXX.com:password"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 40.99.8.192:443...
* Connected to outlook.office365.com (40.99.8.192) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; CN=outlook.com
*  start date: Jul 26 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 25 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "outlook.office365.com" matched cert's "*.office365.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'austin.jackson@XXXX.com'
> POST /ews/odata/Me/sendmail HTTP/1.1
> Host: outlook.office365.com
> Authorization: Basic cmFtYWtyaXNobmEeee29uZGFAdWdhbXNvbHV0aW9ucy5jb2yyhhR2FuZXNoQDEyMzQ1
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 263
>
 looks awesome!"},"ToRecipients": [{"EmailAddress": {"Name": "Austin Jackson","Address": "austin.jackson@XXXX.com"}}]}}' https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/sendmail --header "Content-Type:application/json"  --verbose --user "austin.jackson@XXXX.com:password"
* upload completely sent off: 263 out of 263 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< request-id: ae80a283-1cae-87e2-7f04-71dc1d789d709
< Alt-Svc: h3=":443",h3-29=":443"
< X-CalculatedFETarget: YUYIYIYIUY.internal.outlook.com
< X-BackEndHttpStatus: 401
< Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=ffb990ad1bf848e38b00c70f9d0b99tty; expires=Tue, 23-Apr-2024 06:54:17 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< X-CalculatedBETarget: 0000YYYY1111.abc1234.prod.outlook.com
< X-BackEndHttpStatus: 401
< X-RUM-Validated: 1
< X-RUM-NotUpdateQueriedPath: 1
< X-RUM-NotUpdateQueriedDbCopy: 1
< X-BeSku: WCS6
< X-DiagInfo: TY0PR04MB5402
< X-BEServer: TY0PR04MB5402
< X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1
< X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 401
< X-FEProxyInfo: XXXXYYYY.FRAN01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
< X-FEEFZInfo: PNQ
< X-FEServer: XXXXYYYY
< X-FirstHopCafeEFZ: PNQ
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< X-FEServer: YYYYZZZZ
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""
< Date: Sun, 23 Apr 2023 06:54:17 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host outlook.office365.com left intact
root@ef2ea69fccf8:/opt/airflow#
```

Trying to do the curl through the docker container, but getting the error of Authentication problem. What could be the problem?

As I am testing as I need to do the notification through airflow. But it is giving the error in my airflow code with the below error code.

> raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
> smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail.

Well how to overcome this error of authentication as my password and username is correct